# Regex match and substitute strings of special look

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have a set of strings that look like this:

```
"AK Pz 310u PI-13-5","23.02.2015","07:45:00","23.02.2015","09:20:00","False","True","23.02.2015","07:40:00","2","Common","AK Pz 310u PI-13-5","Common"
```

And using one single regex and `replaceAll` method I need to get **exactly** the following string:

```
2015-02-23 ==> 07:45 AK Pz 310u
```

I have a regex that matches time and date

```
((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.\d\d\d\d)|((([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))
```

I think I should somehow make use of capturing groups.
This part of a the string: "`AK Pz 310u PI-13-5"` always starts with a capital letter and finishes with a number between 1 and 6, so I think it's quite trivial to match that one. 
But how do I substitute everything the regex matches with the needed look? And how can I insert the `==>` sign into the `string.replaceAll` method?
Any ideas?

BTW: probably, if the original task is too difficult, I can create a two-dimensional array of particular capturing groups in regex and then manipulate the output. Maybe you can throw me a hint on how to do this?

Here is the regex101.com link https://regex101.com/r/vT7eK2/3

Comment: Is there a rule to the occurring pattern?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Because the second and fourth entry separated by commas are the same date, so ...

Comment: well, this is how all the strings in the array would look like. I can't do anything about it. All the strings in the set will be of the same pattern

Comment: That's why I am asking if there is a rule, knowing which one to match from?

Comment: it is important to match the first occurance of the date and the first occurence of the time as well as the first entry between the quotes, i.d. we need to match only this: "AK Pz 310u PI-13-5","23.02.2015","07:45:00"
And after that convert it to an appropriate look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for php I world recommend this regexp:

```
#^"(\w+) (\w+) (\w+) (?:.+?)","(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)","(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)"(?:.*?)$#i
```

and replacement pattern:

```
$6-$5-$4 ==> $7:$8 $1 $2 $3
```

I've just tested it on this site https://ru.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html

I think it would not be difficult to translate this php_replace regexp to java regexp

Comment: it works perfectly here: https://regex101.com/r/vT7eK2/4
But, unfortunately, not in java, although I think I made everything right

Comment: Anyway, your answer is the one I need, so I'll tick it as a corrent one.